# one sql statement with two foreigns keys

Tags: sql, mariadb

[image]

So i know the `userID` in advance and also the `booksID`, I want to insert `comments` into `comments` table.

I came with this query :

```
Insert into comments Set ? Where BookIdeaID=?";
```

But i got this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'Where BookIdeaID=\'0\'\' at line 1',
>
> sqlState: '42000',
>
> index: 0,
>
> sql: 'Insert into comments Set comments = `comments` = \'hello\', `userID` = 9 Where BookIdeaID=\'0\'' }

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you stated, you are looking for an insert query, the syntax is as follows:

```
insert into comments (userID, booksID, comments) values(?, ?, ?);
```

The first question mark stands for the `userID`, the second for the `booksID` (not `BookIdeaID`, since this column belongs to another table), and the third for the `comments` string. I would assume that primary key column `id` is auto-incremented, so I am not assigning it a value (it will be computed by MariaDB).

Beware that, since you apparently have defined foreign key constraints on `userID` and `booksID` (which is a good thing), the values that you are inserting in these columns must already exist in the referred tables, otherwise the insert will fail.